# How to parse JSON nested arrays

Tags: java, android, json

```
"sport_events": [
    {
        "id": "sr:match:12606716",
        "scheduled": "2017-09-27T10:00:00+00:00",
        "start_time_tbd": false,
        "status": "closed",
        "tournament_round": {
            "type": "group",
            "number": 1,
            "group": "Gr. 4"
        },
        "season": {
            "id": "sr:season:45960",
            "name": "U17 European Ch.ship QF 17/18",
            "start_date": "2017-09-27",
            "end_date": "2018-04-30",
            "year": "17/18",
            "tournament_id": "sr:tournament:755"
        },
        "tournament": {
            "id": "sr:tournament:755",
            "name": "U17 European Ch.ship QF",
            "sport": {
                "id": "sr:sport:1",
                "name": "Soccer"
            },
            "category": {
                "id": "sr:category:392",
                "name": "International Youth"
            }
        },
        "competitors": [
            {
                "id": "sr:competitor:22646",
                "name": "Russia",
                "country": "Russia",
                "country_code": "RUS",
                "abbreviation": "RUS",
                "qualifier": "home"
            },
            {
                "id": "sr:competitor:22601",
                "name": "Faroe Islands",
                "country": "Faroe Islands",
                "country_code": "FRO",
                "abbreviation": "FRO",
                "qualifier": "away"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: have you at least tried to google something like "parse JSON in Android?"

Comment: Ever parsed json before? Create your pojo-models with right members and for android **you can use the gson-library** instead of old javax.rs

Comment: @LenglBoy its my first time

Comment: while you´re working with android use the gson-Parser. Gson is very simple to use and very comfortable. if you´re working with clear java/javaEE project then use normal java.rs because gson is a 3rd party tool - and overhyped/not nessesarry.

Comment: @LenglBoy my above given API code can be parsed from gson or not.

Comment: it can. but you need to create the classes and attributes. Here are some examples [gson exapmle](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Comment: @LenglBoy any other easy way of doing this ?

Comment: @LenglBoy i am totally new in android development and this is my university project related.

Comment: http://jsonschema2pojo.org/ paste this json there, select java, JSON, GSON, convert it. Then you will get pojo model classes from where you will easily able to parse your JSON

Answer (score 0):

Add gson to your project by adding this into your `build-script.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Now create the classes you need but first correct your json string. I guess you forgot a attributename at the beginning. This is your new best friend: [json formatter online](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

After you corrected your `json-string` and you´ve created your `Wrapper` and `Pojo` model-classes with the needed attributes, you parse the string back into the `wrapper-object` and with `getter/setter` you get change/get data out of it.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Wrapper wrap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
```

Don´t forget try-catch block because there can be many thrown exceptions.
Good luck to you.

[How-to-for-beginner](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)